# Entity Framework with Web Forms missing properties in code behind

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, webforms

I'm trying to get the auto generated ID of a newly inserted record. Using C# code behind I was able to create a quick sample project with my SQL database and successfully retrieved the value using the following code. But in my working project, Intellisense will not provide the property I need, in fact no properties that exist in the db will show up, i.e., in EDS_OnInserted, "ContactID" could not be found:

```
    protected void EDS_OnInserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contact myContact = e.Entity as Contact;
        Label1.Text = "ID = " + myContact.ContactID;
    }

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=CEntities" DefaultContainerName="CEntities" OnInserted="EDS_OnInserted" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EntitySetName="Contacts">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<br />
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="300px" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ContactID" 
    DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactID" HeaderText="ContactID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ContactID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

I'm at loss what is different in my working project.